# Why does strcmp returns 0 when called from within a find_if? C++

Tags: c++, strcmp

I have a vector of elements.
These elements are structs containing a path and I would like to find an element with a specific path.

I tried using **std::find_if**, as shown below in the **UseFindIf** method, but the call to **strcmp** always returns 0 regardless of whether the **const char ptrs** are the same or not.

I then tried using a for loop to go through the iterators of the container, as shown in the **UseForLoop** method, and it worked as expected.

Does anyone know why **strcmp** behaves like this when called within a **find_if**?

In the code below calling **UseFindIf** prints **Found** and calling **UseForLoop** prints **NotFound**

(The **int** member of the struct is irrelevant)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct
{
    string path;
    int aNumber = 9;
};

void UseFindIf(const vector<MyStruct>& container,  const char* _path)
{
    auto itFoundTexture = std::find_if( container.begin(), container.begin(), [&]( const MyStruct& _td ) 
        {
            return strcmp( _td.path.c_str(), _path ) == 0;
        });
        
    cout << (itFoundTexture == container.end() ? "Not Found" : "Found") << endl;
}

void UseForLoop(const vector<MyStruct>& container,  const char* _path)
{
    auto itFoundTexture = container.begin();

    for (; itFoundTexture != container.end(); ++itFoundTexture)
    {
        if (strcmp( itFoundTexture->path.c_str(), _path ) == 0) break;
    }
    
    cout << (itFoundTexture == container.end() ? "Not Found" : "Found") << endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<MyStruct> container;
    MyStruct data;
    data.path = "../assets/test.jpg";
    data.aNumber = 888;
    container.push_back(data);
    
    UseFindIf(container, "../assets/othertest.jpg");
    UseForLoop(container, "../assets/othertest.jpg");

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried writing the lambda so it compares strings instead of char pointers, but same result.

```
void UseFindIf(vector<MyStruct>& container,  const char* _path)
{
    string strTest(_path);
    auto itFoundTexture = std::find_if( container.begin(), container.begin(), [&]( const MyStruct& _td ) 
        {
            return _td.path == strTest;
        });
        
    cout << (itFoundTexture == container.end() ? "Not Found" : "Found") << endl;
}
```

I can also say that the issue is not related to the lambda, I ran  the same lambda outside of the **find_if** and it behaves as expected.

In case it helps, I am using C++20 in my project in VS.
I also tried using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler and same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect `strcmp` to return?  Did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Elephant in the room: Why the in the name of Elmer Fud are you using `strcmp` in C++20 code?

Comment: FYI, `std::string` has `operator==` that compares it with `const char*`, and it does a correct comparison. `auto itFoundTexture = std::find_if( container.begin(), container.end(), [&](const MyStruct& _td { return _td.path == _path; });` would work just fine. Even simpler (but constructing extra string): `auto itFoundTexture = std::find( container.begin(), container.end(), path);`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `std::find()` won't work in this situation since the `vector` elements are `struct`s, not `string`s.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, right, it would need `std::ranges` version with projection: `auto itFoundTexture = std::ranges::find(container.begin(), container.end(), "../assets/test.jpg", &MyStruct::path);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in `UseFindIf()`.  The iterator range you are specifying is `[begin..begin)` instead of `[begin..end)`, so your lambda will never see any of the `vector`'s elements, and `itFoundTexture` will always be set to the `begin` iterator, thus why you always see `Found` regardless of the actual search result (when the vector is not empty).

You need to change this:

```
std::find_if( container.begin(), container.begin(), ...);
                                           ^
```

To this instead:

```
std::find_if( container.begin(), container.end(), ...);
                                           ^
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I have been looking at this for 2 days now. Should I just delete the question just to not polute the site? ^^

Comment: @fpuma • yes, since this is a "typo" kind of issue.  Not useful for posterity.

Comment: Hmmm I can't delete it because it says it already has an answer

Comment: @pfo Yeah, as soon as a question starts getting upvoted answers, it is seen by the community as having value and is locked in.